# ModuleNotFoundError on pytz,yaml, delta even though installed in same python instance

Tags: python, pip

Let's consider carefully the *`pytz`* library (`yaml` and `delta[-spark]` have an identical pattern.).

'`pytz` has been installed via `pip` and then re-confirmed in a couple of different ways:

- Initial installation

```
+ /root/miniconda3/envs/py310/bin/python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

- Here it is in action being installed

```
Collecting pytz
  Downloading pytz-2022.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (499 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 499.4/499.4 kB 44.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00

...
Successfully installed  pytz-2022.7.1
```

Let's try to [re-]install it manually: we get the expected message that it's already present

```
+ /root/miniconda3/envs/py310/bin/python3 -m pip install pytz
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /root/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages 
(from -r requirements_localdev.txt (line 3)) (2022.7.1)
```

Let's run `pytest' in specifically the same python instance:

```
+ /root/miniconda3/envs/py310/bin/python3 -m pytest -s -rA
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.10, pytest-7.2.2, pluggy-1.0.0
```

But `pytz` is not found?

```
 File "/__w/1/s/src/framework/ddex/utils/logger.py", line 15, in <module>
    import pytz
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytz'
```

Note: there are nearly 800 testcases with several dozen dependent packages. Only 21 testcases fail - those associated with `pytz` and the two other libraries that also fail the same way.

Comment: Does `/root/miniconda3/envs/py310/bin/python3 /__w/1/s/src/framework/ddex/utils/logger.py` work?

Comment: out build system is out to lunch, will get back when it does..

Comment: @AKX yes that works.  also `$PYTHON/bin/python3 -c "from  ddex.utils.logger import Logger; l = Logger('x'); l.set_level(1); print('Logger imported')"`  works

Comment: Then it's something else in your test configuration that causes `pytz`'s installation not to be found, e.g. something messing with `sys.path`... Hard to say without further details.

Comment: It might be `pyspark`  related.  I had the tests running on `Docker` but failing on `AzureDevops` with the same dependencies / `requirements.txt` . But it's difficult to definitively sync the two env's and i suspect some small versioning differences crept in

Comment: How is it difficult to definitely sync? Use a `requirements.txt` that's locked down with e.g. `pip-tools`...

Comment: @AKX  There are sections of the _Docker_  vs the ADO build yml that behave differently